# How to make OleDB query read a colon :

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, oledb

I am working on a GPS app and I need to parse the exploded string sent to the app.
 however, SQL query in OleDB doesn't recognize `:` as a character. - *I think that's the error*

I added a field, `Time` on my .accdb with text as data type...

04T16:18:42Z

that is the *time* data the gps is sending..
but I get syntax error if I am using that through (i just made this short, I use vb.net) -
`insert into myTable(Time) values ('" & txtTime.Text & "')`
that is the query I use. I posted the error yesterday, and it seems that, that is the data that causes syntax error.
what should I do to make it work? Or maybe do something like change its time format, split, rewrite? the main goal is for me to save it to the database. thanks

**UPDATE:** this is my code for saving, could you re-arrange it with `parameters` --

```
query = "INSERT INTO tblGPSRoutes(Time,Latitude,Longitude,Elevation,Accuracy,Bearing,Speed)"
query &= " VALUES ('" & txtTime.Text & "','" & txtLat.Text & "','" & txtLong.Text & "','" & txtElev.Text & "','" & txtAccuracy.Text & "','" & txtBearing.Text & "','" & txtSpeed.Text & "')"


        databaseFunctions.ExecuteQuery(query)
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully.")
```

**UPDATE2:** now I am using parameters :

```
Dim con As OleDbConnection
    con = New OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " & Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "markers.accdb")
    con.Open()
    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO tblGPSRoutes(Latitude,Longitude,Elevation,Accuracy,Bearing,Speed) VALUES (@lat,@long,@elev,@acc,@bearing,@speed)"
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
        With cmd.Parameters
            '.AddWithValue("@time", txtTime.Text)'
            .AddWithValue("@lat", txtLat.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@long", txtLong.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@elev", txtElev.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@acc", txtAccuracy.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@bearing", txtBearing.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@speed", txtSpeed.Text)
        End With
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
```

first says, syntax error.. then I removed the `time` data input. then it works.

Comment: Use parameters with `OleDbCommand`

Comment: Why the downvote? You can also use reserved words by enclosing them in [] such as [time]. Yun lang :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Time` is reserved word in Access. So you cannot use it as column name.(I changed it to `MyTime` in example

Use parameters when you add some application's variables to SQL query.
Then you avoid [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Parameterized_statements) and some errors when using special characters in the string value

```
Dim query As String = "insert into myTable(MyTime, Latitude) values (@TextTime, @Latitude)"
//Then create parameters for your databaseFunctions's functions
Dim parameters As New List(Of OleDbParameters)()
With parameters
    .Add(New OleDbParameter("@TextTime", txtTime.Text))
    .Add(New OleDbParameter("@Latitude", txtLat.Text))
End With
databaseFunctions.ExecuteQuery(query, parameters.ToArray())
MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully.")
```

But then you need add/change your `databaseFunctions.ExecuteQuery(query)` - function to take two parameters

```
Public Sub ExecuteQuery(query As String, params As OleDbParameters())
    //Here add parameters to OleDbCommand object and execute command
End Sub
```

Comment: :) just add new parameter for every field/value in your query in same way

Comment: What should I put in `ExecuteQuery` sub? sorry first time using with parameters. `ExecuteNonQuery()` and?

Comment: got it to work, first says, syntax error, I did use parameters, but then I tried to removed the `time` data. it saves. wth is the problem with the time data? argh

Comment: that's why! how'd you know about that?

Comment: [Access reserved words](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx)